# Android String Localization

Tags: android, string

```
<string name="format_full_friendly_date">
    <xliff:g id="month">%1$s</xliff:g>, <xliff:g id="day">%2$s</xliff:g>
</string>
```

can somebody explain this code for string in Android?

Comment: Have you read this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/35004433/5241603

Comment: yeah i read but i doesn't seem to explain the <xliff:g> tag whats  its use

Comment: This one may answer you: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/04/16/android-localization-tips/

Comment: Check this : http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#g and this :
https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/xliff/faq.php